# How can i add two hexadecimal numbers in a register in MIPS?

Tags: mips

$s0 and $s1 hold the values 0x80000000 and 0xD0000000, respectively. What is the value  of **add $s2, $s0,$s1** ?

Comment: You could've just tried this in a MIPS simulator like SPIM or MARS.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate an overflow exception. If you use addu instead, it'll be 0x50000000.